# keep a node js function running without using any calls from front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to have my NodeJs API to keep creating random data in mongodb.

I am avoiding calling it from from client-end since this should be something happening completely at back-end.

```
var autoCreate = function(){
  var randomNumb = (Math.random()* (10-0) + 0).toFixed(0);
  var randomThing = randomstring.generate({
    length: randomNumb,
    charset: 'alphabetic'
  });

  Thing.create({
    name: randomThing,
    readByUser: false 
  }, function(err, thing) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    autoCreate();
  }, randomNumb*1000);
}
```

But how and where do I call this function for the first time. In my Node API file/controller, I can not just write `autoCreate()`, It breaks.

What would be the right way of doing it>

Comment: call `autoCreate` after declaration it will start calling.

Comment: take a look at node child_proceess,https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Okay, There is some unidentified problem with randomstring.generate part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is an active timer, your script will keep on running.

The code in your question has a small flaw, in that it will call `setInterval` every time the function itself is invoked, but the function itself is never invoked.
This means it is not started, and if you were to start it, you will keep adding new intervals right up to the point where the process, the database process or the entire system will crash.

An example using `setInterval`

```
function ping() {
  console.log('ping');
}

setInterval(ping, Math.random() * 1000);
```

Simply start `ping`-ing with a random interval (where the random time is generated once and used as the interval between `ping`s)

An example using `setTimeout` (which is what you seem to want)

```
function ping() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  console.log('ping');

  timer = setTimeout(ping, Math.random() * 1000);
}

//  ensure the timer variable exists in the global scope
var timer;
ping();
```

In this example, you need to start `ping`-ing yourself and it will just keep invoking itself with random intervals.

Comment: No. That still is a problem in node

Comment: what is still a problem? as I have the `setTimeout` variation in several scripts and these happily continue to run until further notice (e.g. a specific condition I've set, or a blunt `CTRL+C`).

Comment: There was some problem with random string generation function . My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to register your autoCreate call

```
setTimeout(autoCreate, 1000);
```

This will register a call to your autoCreate function every 1 sec.

Also make a call to the autoCreate function at the last line of your callback to MongoClient.connect function.

Comment: You seem to not have understood the problem. It isn't about calling it recursively but for the first time. Where do I make a call to autoCreate function

Comment: Above setTimeOut won't get called 'every' 1 second. It will be called only once.

Comment: are you using mongoose or connecting to mongodb via the native mongodb node.js driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can call after declaration, no client interaction.

```
var autoCreate = function(){
    var randomNumb = (Math.random()* (10-0) + 0).toFixed(0);
     var randomThing = randomstring.generate({
    length: randomNumb,
    charset: 'alphabetic'
  });

   Thing.create({
    name: randomThing,
    readByUser: false 
  }, function(err, thing) {
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    });

   setInterval(function() {
  autoCreate();
  }, randomNumb*1000);

  }

autoCreate(); //Call here
```

Comment: I did. The application stops working at all in this case.

Comment: There is a bug where `setInterval` will be called every time `autoCreate` triggers. (either move `setInterval` outside the `autoCreate`, or replace it with `setTimeout`).

Comment: You have a point. There was a bug :) Thanks for that part but Node still does not allow to initiate a function outside of any function

Answer (score 0):

The best way to automate tasks at backend is to use cron jobs. Here is a module to the rescue [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron). Here is an example -

```
  var autoCreate = function(){
    var randomNumb = (Math.random()* (10-0) + 0).toFixed(0);
    var randomThing = randomstring.generate({
      length: randomNumb,
      charset: 'alphabetic'
    });

    Thing.create({
      name: randomThing,
      readByUser: false 
    }, function(err, thing) {
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    });
  }

var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 30 11 * * 1-5', function() {
  autoCreate();
  /*
   * Runs every weekday (Monday through Friday)
   * at 11:30:00 AM. It does not run on Saturday
   * or Sunday.
   */
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```

You can set the cron pattern according to your need.